# Ruby return unless block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a field from github webhook - `webhook.repository.private` - which checks if created repository was private (boolean). I want use `return if` block to handle scenario:
check if `webhook.repository.private` is true and if not call new class `PublicRepositoryCreated` but if this is true - return and execute `fields_hash`

code below:

```
      def required_fields
        PublicRepositoryCreated.new(webhook).call unless webhook.repository.private

        fields_hash
      end

      private

      def fields_hash
        {
          'fields' => {
            'summary' => 'summary',
            'description' => 'description',
            'project' => '123'
          }
        }
      end
```

Right now it seems that `fields_hash` is still executed even when `webhook.repository.private` is `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways of solving your problem.

You can either :

1. call your function and return

```
def required_fields
  PublicRepositoryCreated.new(webhook).call && return unless webhook.repository.private

  fields_hash
end
```

2. return your function

```
def required_fields
  return PublicRepositoryCreated.new(webhook).call unless webhook.repository.private

  fields_hash
end
```

3. use a ternary

```
def required_fields
  webhook.repository.private ? fields_hash : PublicRepositoryCreated.new(webhook).call
end
```